# SnakeGame: How to deal with a interrupt thread and with a deadlock

Tags: java, multithreading, deadlock

everyone. I'm doing a game for a programming class that consists in two snakes that walk in a bord in opposite directions. They need to block in
barriers and i use coordination for them to not go against each other. Which means that the second one trying to acess a cell, will need to wait till the first unblocks the cell. I already read a lot of topics in this website and i still didn't find a solution to my problem.

Right now i already have the snakes moving all around the board and blocking in the barriers. My two big issues right e that i appreciate any help are follows ones:

1- There's specific situations, for example, two snakes walking paralell, that when they try to turn the direction towards the other snake they both block and the game
stops there, causing a deadlock. Just one can stop, while the other waits for the first one to unblock the cell. I stil didn't find a solution for the specific issue. If they don't collide
in the direction of each one, there's no problem. One snake waits for the other one to clear the cel.. i already read in here a solution about using a CountDownLatch but don't know how to implement it.

2 When the snakes blocks in a barrier, goes on wait(). Then i make her move again cliking in a cell of the board and the snake needs to recalculate a new way to go to the cell i cliked. Which means i need to change the movement from random to a specific one. The teacher said us to interrupt the thread, make her leave the method she was doing (moveNextCell() ) and recalculte the next movement again.
The problem here is that i can handle the interruption but don't know how to activate the thread again. I read it, and don't know if i interpret it bad, that after a thread it's interrupt, i can't start it again, so i need to make a copy of it. But right now i don't know how i can do it in my code since the new thread would need the actual position, color, etc of the snake.

Right now i'm not able to do both situations.

The cell code ( that blocks the snakes in case of barrier or one snake want to use the other one cell ) is the follow:

public synchronized void reserveCell(Snake snakeID){
               this .snakeID = snakeID ;

```
           while (type .equals("Barrier" )){
                  try {
                       wait();
                 } catch (InterruptedException e ) {
                        // When snake it's blocked and we interrupt it, comes to this part!
                       Thread. currentThread().interrupt();
                        snakeID.doSpecificMovement();


                 }
          }
           while (inUse ){
                  try {
                       wait();
                 } catch (InterruptedException e ) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                 }
          }

          setSnakeID( snakeID);
           inUse = true ;
   }
```

The snake code ( that makes it move ) is the follow:

public void run(){
               while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()){
                     moveNextCell( currentX, currentY); // asks the next cell, if possible adds the cell to the body of snake and updates the GUI
                     setRandomDirection(); // define the direction of next move.

```
                  try {
                        sleep(gameSpeed);
                 } catch (InterruptedException e ) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                 }

                 gameOver(); // when the snakes reachs the end of the board finishs
          }

   }
```

I would appreciate any help that can make me progress in my work. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Is using threads part of your requirements? It looks like it would be much simpler as a single threaded program.

Comment: Banthar, first thanks for your help. Unfortunately yes, it's a coordination and synchronization class so they force us to use multiple threads!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming situations you mention in point #1 look like this:
[image: deadlocking snakes]

You cannot do much about it. If snakes are separate threads, they do not know about each other and cannot themselves resolve the conflict. Your professor should specify how to resolve such deadlocks. The simplest solution would be to keep the snakes deadlocked until user interacts and chooses different destination. You can also add timeout to `wait()` method. If cell doesn't become available after some time, randomly choose different direction.

There are two ways to solve the second issue:

1. You can stop the thread completely and then start new thread with new destination. You would have to remove `InterruptedException` from all catches and propagate it up to `run()` method:

   ```
   void goToDestination() throws InterruptedException {
       ...
   }

   @Override
   public void run() {
       try {
           goToDestination();
       } catch(InterruptedException e) {
           // end thread
           return;
       }
   }
   ```

   This way `interrupt()` will be able to stop the thread. You can restart it like this:

   ```
   // interrupt and wait until thread actually finishes
   snake.thread.interrupt();
   snake.thread.join();

   // change the destination
   snake.destination = newDestination;

   // restart the thread
   snake.thread = new Thread(snake);
   snake.thread.start();
   ```
2. You can also change the destination and interrupt just the main method:

   ```
   @Override
   public void run() {
       while(true) {
           try {
               goToDestination(destination);
           } catch (InterruptedException e) {
               // try again with changed destination
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   When user chooses new destination:

   ```
   // set new destination
   snake.destination = newDestination;

   // interrupt old goToDestination
   snake.thread.interrupt();
   ```

Comment: Banthar, can't thank you enough for your help!

About the first issue, it's exactly that! Just in those situations they block!I'm gonna try the timeout on wait() and also ask my teachers to me more specific about the solution for the issue.

About the second issue, i'm going to try that solution now! After i give feedback. :)

Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

banthar, i just tried your second solution and worked great! I would never thought about this, all this exception things it's really a new thing to me!

Like before, i'm gonna say what i did in order to help the others.

As banthar said, all methods that i was using that would lead to the interrupt, i put them going to the run() of the snake. So this way i was able to stop the thread and make a new one. Then i just add to use a method to change the direction and make a new start like banthar put.

Problem solved, thank you very much and hope this can help more people!

Answer (score 0):

About the first issue, i already solved it. In case someone find this useful for their problem, i'm gonna post my solution.

The problem, as Banthar said, is that the snakes don't know about the other ones. Which means that in this specific two situations, they would block each other, waiting for the other to move => Deadlock.

The solution here is for one of them warn the other "Hey Snake, i'm blocked. Don't block waiting for me or we both get stuck".

Searching the internet i found a lot of solutions using a ThreadPool that would coordinate all them but that was just to much for my problem.

So i made a atrribute in Snake called snakeBlocked that turns true whhen the snakes blocks. The operation is made in the Cell when the snake trys to acess it. So when the second snake trys to acess a cell with a snake, the cell have a method to find out what's the value of the snakeBlocked of the snake stuck in the cell. After that turn out easy.

If the snake that wants to acess the cell knows there's a blocked snake there, she changes her direction.

Hope it can help someone since i was stuck in those for a long time.

About the issue #2 gonna try it now, after i come here if i can come to a solution!